# While loop that prints a random number between 1 and 10 and stops when the number is N

Tags: python, random, while-loop

This is what I've got, but this only generates a random number once and prints that number infinitely:

```
import random

x = random.randint(0,10)
y = 7
while x != y:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it, you need to generate a new random number inside the loop:

```
import random

x = random.randint(0,10)
y = 7
while x != y:
    print(x)   #Print old (non-7) random number
    x = random.randint(0,10)  #pick a new number.  I hope it's 7 so we can end this madness

print("You found {0}.  Congrats.  Go have a beer.".format(y))
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like (moving the condition inside the while):

```
stop_at = 7
while True:
    num = random.randint(0, 10)
    if num == stop_at:
        break
    print num
```

Or, a complete re-factor:

```
from itertools import starmap, repeat, takewhile
from random import randint

for num in takewhile(lambda L: L != 7, starmap(randint, repeat( (0, 10) ))):
    print num
```

Comment: I'm always torn on this one.  Should I create an infinite loop with a break, or should I unroll the first iteration of the loop and put it before? ... It makes me wish python had an `until` statement that other languages have.

Comment: @mgilson Or a way to start a loop at an arbitrary point rather than from the condition. That solves the more general case of partial first or last iterations.

Comment: @mgilson Yep, I'm always torn - could be re-done as a for, which makes the condition clearer... (sort of - see example)

Comment: @agf -- You're right, but that seems a little too close to `goto` *shudder*.  As someone who works with ancient Fortran daily, I don't want anything remotely close to `goto` to mar the beauty of python...

Comment: @JonClements -- I really don't think that's clearer (I even had a difficult time groking it at first).  It is clever though :).  I wouldn't have thought of using a `for` for something like this.